# The controller for path '/Admin/Admin/Index' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC project that works fine and I decided to use "Area" because it is so hard to find controllers and views. I am also using _Layout.

When I added Area > Admin into my project, I had problems. I tried to visit "http://localhost/Admin/Admin/Index", I had the error below...

```
The controller for path '/Admin/Admin/Index' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

I think the problem is caused by a Layout but I dont know how to solve this. Can anybody give me clue?

Comment: This path should work if your controller is named `AdminController`. If it has a different name, e.g. `HomeController` (inside the Admin area), then use `/Admin/Home/Index`.

Comment: @PeterB, actually it calls the view If I visit /Admin/Admin/Index. but it throws the error when it hits @{Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Home");} in Layout

Comment: That is essential info, that should have been in the question... I will create an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RenderAction` call should look like this when the possibility exists that it is called from inside an Area while referring to a non-area location:

```
@Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Home", new { area = "" })
```